# Automating Monthly Small Business Task (VBA, VC++, Excel, Access, Quickbooks, etc)

Tags: c++, pdf, excel, fax, vba

Let me start by giving a quick background on myself (please forgive me). I have an intense interest in programming and computers/technical things in general. I took a year of C/C++ in college and a semester of assembly. I have messed around with Visual BASIC. So, almost all of my programming knowledge is limited to these three languages in order of proficiency:

C/C++
Assembly
Visual BASIC

I have a job at a small business that can't justify hiring a trained/"certified" programmer where I have tasked myself with automating a process that must be completed on a monthly basis. It involves:

1. Sending faxes that are to be filled out with numbers
2. Receiving those faxes that are returned (all incoming faxes go to network folder as PDF)
3. Collecting the numbers from received faxes and entering these numbers into Excel (some are Word format for some reason) and then into QuickBooks after calculations
4. Sending emails
5. Receiving replies to these emails that contain numbers
6. Manually entering these numbers into Excel and then QuickBooks after calculations
7. Collecting numbers from a website written in Javascript. Numbers from website can be outputted to *.csv file.
8. Finally, printing invoices out from QuickBooks using the calculated numbers that have been entered.

My goal is to automate this entire process. As of now, everything is done manually. Emails and faxes are sent one at a time. Numbers from website are read and entered into Excel one at a time. Numbers are put into QB and invoices are printed one at a time.

So far I have added an email scheduling add-on to Outlook that automatically sends the emails every month. I am working on setting up faxes to be sent automatically (the only thing I can think of off the top of my head is manipulating Windows Scan/Fax with API library in either VB or VC++).

Also, I am automating the calculations that must be performed in order to prep the collected numbers for entry into QB using VBA/Excel and, potentially, Access.

Right now I'm brainstorming a way to automatically collect the numbers (along with customer name) from the returned faxes. My idea was to create a new fax sheet that forced the customer to "bubble in" the numbers like a ScanTron sheet. This way I could write a program (perhaps in C++) to parse the PDF looking for a certain colored pixel in a specific spot in order to piece together the number (I wonder if I could automatically OCR the PDFs and collect the customer name simply by extracting text from each PDF?) which could then be sent to a database or perhaps directly to an Excel sheet (the Excel sheets have to stay so that hard copies of data can be printed--though I supposed this could be accomplished without Excel).

And lastly, since some customers refuse to use any of those methods available to them, we have to manually call some of them. Once I am finished with all of the aforementioned work I would like to develop a way to allow customers to call a specific phone number and key in the information via voice prompt which would then deposit the information in database somewhere. This will be complicated and require special equipment so it will be last and lowest priority. Not worried about this right now.

Since my experience with programming is only moderate (though I'm sure my working knowledge will expand quickly once I get started since a lot of it is already in my brain somewhere) I wanted to give myself the best advantage and tools possible to tackle this project before I got so far into it that changing my methods would waste a lot of time/work. To sum up, I need to make an outline of exactly what I need to do/learn and what techniques/applications to use.

This is the site I always come to when searching for my programming questions and I have come to the conclusion that the people here are generally extremely knowledgeable, patient and helpful. I will appreciate any contribution of information, advice and/or insights no matter how small. I realize that in this situation I am the "beggar" and thus will be grateful for whatever I get.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Before anyone says anything: I have "UTFSE" extensively and have assimilated lots of info from it. However, we all know that there's no equal to a human's problem solving capabilities--especially when proficient in the specific field.

Answer (score 0):

Nice work! You are definitely on the right track. That was a lot of information so I apologize if I repeat anything you already know.

1) **Faxes** - Microsoft has an excellent resource for learning how to send faxes (they even provide the code). Check this out: *[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693482(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693482%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*

2) You will have to **OCR the PDF's** (as you mentioned) and then you can extract the information. But (as you seem to understand), you cannot modify a pdf with c++.

3) C++ does allow you to save (and open) a file in Excel format. However, **it's a very complicated format and will probably cause some problems.** One of them is that it will want to save all of your data to one cell. **A way to get around this is to I/O to Excel with .csv files.** A comma separates the columns and a new line the rows. For example,

A1, B1, C1

A2, B2, C2

A3, B3, C3

Excel will open and read these files correctly. However, you won't be able to format font, borders, etc... automatically.

This is the extent of my knowledge, I have never worked with emails or Quickbooks. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your input. If I end up editing Office documents en masse with C++ I will likely just end up "unzipping" the file and editing the XML directly. This would seem to me as simple as finding a library for opening ZIP files and then just doing standard text editing on the XML files. Of course this will likely involve a lot of time invested in studying XML, but surely not much more than relearning a lot of the stuff I need to do in C++ or even Visual BASIC.